# Correct usage of pyplot.xticks() in an Ipython notebook

Tags: python, matplotlib

It's a bar graph with 11 bars. I wanted to modify the x-axis labels exactly as described [here](http://matplotlib.org/api/pyplot_api.html#matplotlib.pyplot.xticks), but it throws a 
`TypeError: 'list' object is not callable`. The amount of items is alright, square-brackets around 0,...,10 lead to the same result. Other posts dealing with this error didn't help me much (things like list(x) instead of list[x]).

If I leave out the xticks-block it works fine – what do I need to change?

```
%matplotlib inline
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

plt.bar(range(len(partei)),stimmen,linewidth=0, #stimmen = 11-integer array, len(partei)=11
        color=["red","black","blue",...,"purple","black","darkred"], #11 colors
        align="center"
        )

plt.xticks((0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10),
           ("red","black","blue",...,"black","darkred") #11 colors
           )
```

Comment: I'm guessing at some point you accidentally assigned a list to `plt.xticks`.